# Catch event when users scrolls up to a certain element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p onscroll="function(){alert('scroll');}"></p>
```

I want to catch an event when I scroll to a certain element.

I'me code in the middle of a page. When I scroll to it, alert doesn't appear. By the way, in console there is no errors.

Why does this happen, and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`onscroll` event doesn't work that way.

The event is dispatched when you are actually scrolling on that specific element. If that element has no scroll bar it won't work.

For example, you have a long HTML body that you can scroll over, you have a p element inside it that has no scroll bar. And you do some scrolling. You would be doing that scrolling on the document itself and not the p element.

If you need to show an alert when an element enters your viewport you should use IntersectionObserver API

---

#### Example 1

Scrolling on the red paragraph or the white document, both of them still dispatch the document event listener.

```js
let containerScrollCount = 0;
let textScrollCount = 0;

const alertScrollCounts = () => {
  console.log(`container was scrolled ${containerScrollCount} times`);
  console.log(`text was scrolled ${textScrollCount} times`);
}

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  textScrollCount++;
  alertScrollCounts();
})

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  containerScrollCount++;
  alertScrollCounts();
})
```

```css
#text {
  background: red;
  max-width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquet venenatis hendrerit. Quisque id interdum sem. Etiam at iaculis augue. Mauris fermentum imperdiet velit, ut bibendum odio lacinia ut. Suspendisse sed varius velit. Quisque ultricies bibendum velit, in mattis odio venenatis sed. Ut eget eleifend nisl, vel sodales risus. Integer purus risus, finibus eget congue nec, mattis nec felis. Nullam sit amet venenatis est.

Phasellus ut pretium ante, vitae hendrerit elit. Duis ac diam et nunc rhoncus finibus. Proin dictum sed ipsum ut pellentesque. Aenean vestibulum fermentum malesuada. Nulla feugiat risus eget nisi cursus scelerisque. Vivamus ullamcorper efficitur metus in congue. Proin porttitor urna in magna varius rutrum. Maecenas dui enim, volutpat sed lorem nec, tincidunt vulputate ante. Integer tincidunt tellus sit amet lacinia tincidunt. Fusce imperdiet, urna condimentum semper sodales, ligula nulla cursus lorem, at elementum sapien dui eget elit. Donec pharetra egestas pulvinar. Nullam a nisi et nunc laoreet feugiat non ut sem. Donec efficitur diam lorem, sed ultrices quam vestibulum sit amet. Aenean tempor erat dolor, viverra efficitur augue cursus blandit. Quisque in efficitur tellus. Integer blandit aliquet ante sit amet tristique.

Vivamus at tortor at orci euismod semper ac quis lacus. Ut pharetra sit amet quam non laoreet. Integer ac blandit nunc. Suspendisse mollis sapien odio, ac convallis sapien semper non. Nunc finibus, neque vitae viverra cursus, leo turpis eleifend metus, et ornare eros ligula et orci. Vivamus rutrum et turpis at congue. Phasellus suscipit, lorem vel pharetra convallis, urna ipsum commodo orci, vitae mollis nulla tortor in dui. Nam rhoncus, arcu ut egestas suscipit, nulla lacus gravida nisl, sed porttitor dolor sem gravida lacus. Cras nulla nisl, cursus sed dictum vitae, fermentum nec tellus. Donec et nisi eget nisi elementum ultricies id non mi. Integer quam massa, porttitor ac tortor vitae, elementum eleifend odio. Morbi malesuada faucibus nisi, ac volutpat sem vestibulum eu. Donec blandit nunc non tellus pellentesque cursus a vel risus. Suspendisse quis venenatis risus, eu consectetur neque. Etiam tincidunt lectus dui, a mattis arcu scelerisque id.

Nulla vel erat at sapien rhoncus venenatis ut eget velit. Duis eu dolor porta, dapibus dui in, lacinia risus. Mauris commodo dui et eros condimentum, at feugiat dui vehicula. Nulla eu nulla viverra, laoreet mi eget, euismod nisi. Pellentesque lorem odio, consequat imperdiet sodales sit amet, tincidunt in odio. Proin in urna eget dolor blandit ullamcorper. Pellentesque non erat ante. Quisque ornare arcu id ex accumsan, sit amet suscipit lorem euismod. Nam eu turpis ultricies, luctus nisi a, facilisis justo. Vivamus ullamcorper lectus at rutrum vestibulum. Duis vehicula augue vitae imperdiet sagittis.

Mauris in posuere justo. Etiam blandit turpis non tincidunt blandit. Aenean vestibulum, lacus non dapibus egestas, leo lorem vestibulum odio, mollis fringilla felis eros sit amet nulla. Vestibulum a suscipit leo, a tempor lectus. Praesent justo enim, facilisis quis purus nec, convallis efficitur velit. Cras metus turpis, pulvinar tristique tincidunt et, consequat a neque. Vivamus vehicula id orci at tincidunt.</p>
<div>
```

---

#### Example 2

Scrolling on red dispatches its own listener. Why? Because it has a scroll bar.

```js
let containerScrollCount = 0;
let textScrollCount = 0;

const alertScrollCounts = () => {
  console.log(`container was scrolled ${containerScrollCount} times`);
  console.log(`text was scrolled ${textScrollCount} times`);
}

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  textScrollCount++;
  alertScrollCounts();
})

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  containerScrollCount++;
  alertScrollCounts();
})
```

```css
#text {
  background: red;
  max-width:50%;
  max-height:300px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquet venenatis hendrerit. Quisque id interdum sem. Etiam at iaculis augue. Mauris fermentum imperdiet velit, ut bibendum odio lacinia ut. Suspendisse sed varius velit. Quisque ultricies bibendum velit, in mattis odio venenatis sed. Ut eget eleifend nisl, vel sodales risus. Integer purus risus, finibus eget congue nec, mattis nec felis. Nullam sit amet venenatis est.

Phasellus ut pretium ante, vitae hendrerit elit. Duis ac diam et nunc rhoncus finibus. Proin dictum sed ipsum ut pellentesque. Aenean vestibulum fermentum malesuada. Nulla feugiat risus eget nisi cursus scelerisque. Vivamus ullamcorper efficitur metus in congue. Proin porttitor urna in magna varius rutrum. Maecenas dui enim, volutpat sed lorem nec, tincidunt vulputate ante. Integer tincidunt tellus sit amet lacinia tincidunt. Fusce imperdiet, urna condimentum semper sodales, ligula nulla cursus lorem, at elementum sapien dui eget elit. Donec pharetra egestas pulvinar. Nullam a nisi et nunc laoreet feugiat non ut sem. Donec efficitur diam lorem, sed ultrices quam vestibulum sit amet. Aenean tempor erat dolor, viverra efficitur augue cursus blandit. Quisque in efficitur tellus. Integer blandit aliquet ante sit amet tristique.

Vivamus at tortor at orci euismod semper ac quis lacus. Ut pharetra sit amet quam non laoreet. Integer ac blandit nunc. Suspendisse mollis sapien odio, ac convallis sapien semper non. Nunc finibus, neque vitae viverra cursus, leo turpis eleifend metus, et ornare eros ligula et orci. Vivamus rutrum et turpis at congue. Phasellus suscipit, lorem vel pharetra convallis, urna ipsum commodo orci, vitae mollis nulla tortor in dui. Nam rhoncus, arcu ut egestas suscipit, nulla lacus gravida nisl, sed porttitor dolor sem gravida lacus. Cras nulla nisl, cursus sed dictum vitae, fermentum nec tellus. Donec et nisi eget nisi elementum ultricies id non mi. Integer quam massa, porttitor ac tortor vitae, elementum eleifend odio. Morbi malesuada faucibus nisi, ac volutpat sem vestibulum eu. Donec blandit nunc non tellus pellentesque cursus a vel risus. Suspendisse quis venenatis risus, eu consectetur neque. Etiam tincidunt lectus dui, a mattis arcu scelerisque id.

Nulla vel erat at sapien rhoncus venenatis ut eget velit. Duis eu dolor porta, dapibus dui in, lacinia risus. Mauris commodo dui et eros condimentum, at feugiat dui vehicula. Nulla eu nulla viverra, laoreet mi eget, euismod nisi. Pellentesque lorem odio, consequat imperdiet sodales sit amet, tincidunt in odio. Proin in urna eget dolor blandit ullamcorper. Pellentesque non erat ante. Quisque ornare arcu id ex accumsan, sit amet suscipit lorem euismod. Nam eu turpis ultricies, luctus nisi a, facilisis justo. Vivamus ullamcorper lectus at rutrum vestibulum. Duis vehicula augue vitae imperdiet sagittis.

Mauris in posuere justo. Etiam blandit turpis non tincidunt blandit. Aenean vestibulum, lacus non dapibus egestas, leo lorem vestibulum odio, mollis fringilla felis eros sit amet nulla. Vestibulum a suscipit leo, a tempor lectus. Praesent justo enim, facilisis quis purus nec, convallis efficitur velit. Cras metus turpis, pulvinar tristique tincidunt et, consequat a neque. Vivamus vehicula id orci at tincidunt.</p>
<div>
```